# using / forward slash as a parameter

Tags: php, apache, url

I have a single page index.php. I would like to accept parameters in the form `/value`. Right now, if I add anything after a `/`, it assumes I'm trying to access a separate file and errors out. Is there a way I could accept params by adding `/value`

Comment: That's usually done by the webserver. The server can rewrite `/value` into `index.php?key=value`

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache, IIS, ...

Comment: @Ander2, Sorry, too tired to think. I'm using Apache2.

Answer (score 1):

Maby you can have a look at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/).
This is a light weight framework and can do all your url desires.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I usually use another framework, and I'm intentionally not using a framework on this project because I want it to be a single and simple page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use apache's rewrite module. Check that `rewrite_module` is active.
Then you could place a simple `.htaccess` file in you directory with the following rules to do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?value=$1 [L,NS]
```

This rules with activate rewrite engine and place everythin after `/` into `value` variable.

Have a look to the rewrite [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) and then adjust the rules to your own.